# Logitech Z623 Speakers crackling on PC only?

Tags: logitech-speakers

One day I just turned on my computer and the speakers started crackling at random points in music, movies etc.

I connected them to my iPod and the crackling was gone.

Is this something to do with my sound card? How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provoke the crackling by wiggling the cable when connected to your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the cracking if happens while turning the volume knob up or down, try cleaning it with a blower for starters. Then, if it still prevails, try rubbing the ends of the 3.5 mm connector lightly with a sand paper  and connect again. Apart from that, the satellite speakers are weak in the 200Hz region and at high volumes, they sound like cracked paper for the beats of the mentioned frequency region and sound normal with lower volumes.

If the cracking still persists and your z623 is under warranty, get it checked at the service center.

Thanks...